# Freemember Reset Password

Tags: freemember

Having difficulty getting the reset password functionality to work.

I've got the forgot password template set up which then sends you to the reset password template on submission.

On the reset password page I just get an instant message of "Sorry, the link you clicked on does not appear to be valid, or has expired"

I receive the reset password email but clicking on the link gives me the following message "The password reset token does not appear to be valid. Please check the link you followed."

Not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies I didn't have the reset parameter in the form

```
{exp:freemember:forgot_password return="account/forgot_sent" reset="account/reset"}
    <!-- forgot password template -->
{/exp:freemember:forgot_password}
```